# Go squirrel setMap lat long

Tags: go

Instead of doing something like

```
INSERT INTO locations (address, created_at, updated_at, geometry)
        values ($1, $2, $3, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($4, $5), 4326));
```

where the $4 and $5 are long, lat

How can I use squirrel's setMap (https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/squirrel#InsertBuilder.SetMap) to build `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($4, $5), 4326)`?